# How to create custom txDb using GenomeFeatures?

Tags: bioconductor, genomefeatures

I have orf virus sequence in GFF3 format. I am trying to create a txDb using `GenomicFeatures::makeTxDbFromGFF()` function. But, it is not able to capture any CDS:

```
transcript_nrow: 0
exon_nrow: 0
cds_nrow: 0
```

Command I used:

```
orf <- GenomicFeatures::makeTxDbFromGFF("orf.gff3",format="gff3")
```

[Link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AY386263.1) to the genome in NCBI.